# Convert an existing objective-c static library to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks

I am in the process of trying to convert an existing objective-c static library to swift.  My goal is to update a few files from objective-c to swift at a time, so for a few weeks my project will consist of objective-c files and swift files.

I have creating one new swift file and removed its objective-c counter part.  I also creating a bridging header when xcode asked.

When I build I get the following error:

> 'Swift is not supported for static libraries'

I have looked around a bit and it seems like I need to create a framework.  I have found many examples on how to create a new framework, but nothing on how to convert and old static library project to a framework.  Is this possible or do I need to start a new project from scratch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

- Add a new cocoa touch framework as a TARGET in your existing static linked library project.
- In the Build Phases, adding all the .m, .mm, .c, .cpp, .metal, etc. into "\Build Phases\Compile Sources" phase of your static linked framework target.
- Put the headers that you want to exposed in to "\Build Phases\Headers".
- Remember to check the Mach-O Type setting in your Build Settings, it should be "Static Library".
  Then the app that wants to use this framework just need to include the headers as #import and add the framework into "Build Phases\Link Binary With Libraries" of your App Target.

Here is a tutorial from [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios)

The tutorial builds a static library then converts it to iOS framework so you can try the last half.

Comment: When I do all this and build I get 'Swift is not supported for static libraries'

Comment: Also tried creating a brand new framework project to see if I could get things working and compare to my existing project.  Everything works great until I add the first swift file and I get 'Swift is not supported for static libraries'.  Not sure why I am getting that as I am creating a brand new framswork, not a static library.  What am I missing?